# Spark: format of an rdd to convert to dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Assuming I am having the following rdd:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(('a'.toString,1.1,Array(1.1,2.2),0),
                             ('b'.toString,1.5,Array(1.4,4.2),3),
                             ('d'.toString,2.1,Array(3.3,7.4),4)))

>>>rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String,Double,Array[Double],Int)]
```

And I want to write the output to `csv` format by using `.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")` which takes a dataframe.

So firstly i need to convert the current schema to -> `rdd[(String, String, String, String, String)]` and after convert it to df. I tried the following:

```
rdd.map { case((a,b,c,d)) => (a,b,c.mkString(","),d)}
```

but this outputs:

```
rdd[(string,double,string,int)]
```

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: There is a library for this purpose [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/),which works for versions previous 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

To work with Tuples, you have to know how many elements you're going to put in them and define the use case yourself. Hence, to work with variable number of elements, you'll probably need to work with some collection.
For your use case, something like this can work:

```
rdd.map { case((a,b,c,d)) => a +: (b +: c) :+ d}.map(_.mkString(","))
```

This will result in an `RDD[String]` corresponding to each line of the csv file.
You're prepending and appending the other elements to the `Array` "c" to result in a single `Array`.

Comment: this answer is obvious. I was looking for something more elegant. btw `c` has more than 300 values.

Comment: Should've mentioned that in the question. Updated the answer.